# Unable to access view from my activity's method? (null object reference)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a class called **TouchImageView** that extends **ImageView**, it basically implements an image viewer similar to the one in Android's "Photos".

When the user single taps the *TouchImageView*, I want two other views inside "activity_viewimage" to change visibility by calling a method in the main activity **ViewImageActivity**:

```
@Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e)
    {
        ViewImageActivity viewImageActivity= new ViewImageActivity();
        viewImageActivity.toggleTopBottomViews();
    }
```

And now in *ViewImageActivity*

```
public class ViewImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private View bottomView;
private View topView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewimage);

    bottomView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_view);
    topView = findViewById(R.id.top_view);
}

public void toggleTopBottomViews ()
{
    if (topView.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE && bottomView.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE)
    {
        bottomView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        topView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        bottomView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        topView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

The error stack:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getVisibility()' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at com.example.zigo.photoencryption.ViewImageActivity.toggleTopBottomViews(ViewImageActivity.java:273)
                                                                                  at com.example.zigo.photoencryption.TouchImageView$GestureListener.onSingleTapConfirmed(TouchImageView.java:764)
                                                                                  at android.view.GestureDetector$GestureHandler.handleMessage(GestureDetector.java:300)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 1):

You NEVER create an Activity via new.  It won't get correctly initialized, initialization of activities is handled only by the framework in response to a request to start an Activity.  Even if you could create an Activity via new it wouldn't help you, you'd be creating a new Activity which would have different views.  (And here you're getting NPEs because onCreate is not being called at all, not by the framework because it isn't started correctly, and not by you).

Instead what you ought to do is pass in the views who's visibility you want to toggle into your detector so it can do it directly, or have the activity which creates the gesture detector pass in a callback and do it itself.

There's a chance here that you just really don't understand what an activity is-  if you think you can just add views at any time by creating an Activity, then you need to go back to tutorials on what an activity is.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: How would you pass in the views? I moved everything around and I'm trying to do inside the onCreate (findViewById(R.id.touchimageview).topView = findViewById(R.id.topview) after making topView a public variable in the touchimageview class, but that's not working